# When hackers hike

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

One day you were taking a hike in some foothills somewhere near the East Coast of the US. It was clear another hac– umm, *hiker* had already been there when you came across the following munged signage.

[image: look around]

There was a note attached to it which read:

```
   -T+H-E--K-E+Y+-I+S+
   +I-N-V+I-S-I+B-L-E+

Y-E-T+T-H+E+M-E+S+S-A+G-E
I+S-+O-B-S+C+U-R+E+D-+B+Y
T+H+A-T+--W+H+I+C-H-++I-S

   -C+O+N-C-E+A-L-E+D-
   -×+×-×+×I+N×+×-×-×+
   P+L-A+I-N-S+I-G-H-T
```

**Where were you? What was the arrow pointing to?**

Comment: Do we need to do image analysis? That is, would the puzzle be unsolvable if we printed it out?

Comment: @Deusovi - You may or may not need to do _analysis_, but it would indeed be unsolvable on paper.

Comment: The PNG file is corrupted.  *Mathematica* refuses to open it, and GIMP displays a different lower half than Chrome and Windows do.

Comment: @2012rcampion At this point I won't say much on that, but I've added the [tag:computer-puzzle] tag.

Comment: @2012rcampion And Firefox doesn't display it at all.

Comment: I've found out that there are 23 extra bytes in the second `IDAT` chunk.  Try looking for text strings in there...

Comment: does solving this puzzle needs knowledge of any computer language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As seen in the answer from *2012rcampion* fixing the corrupted PNG image reveals the next step:
> KCTVCEDCA
> Using the [Viginere Encoder](http://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher) (not decoder) and the key INVISIBLE we get:
> [SPODUMENE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spodumene)
> <s>I guess the [Black Hills](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hills) mentioned in the Wikipedia article are a little too far away from the East Coast. Maybe you are in [Huntington](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntington,_Massachusetts) (see the image in the Spodumene article). [Encyclopædia Britannica](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Spodumene) mentions more locations in Massachusetts.</s>
> As *Daniil Agashiyev* found out the answer to both question is probably **Hiddenite** which is a [variety of Spodumene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiddenite) and a [town in North Carolina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiddenite,_North_Carolina).
> There is also a red herring in the question. The + and - signs can be splitted to groups of 8 and interpreted as ASCII. The result is *CrImSoNfIsH*.

Comment: Great guess; you're very close! However, it's not quite right - the intended answer(s) to both questions are the same. Perhaps read those articles more closely. ;)

Comment: Is the crimson fish a red herring, or part of the solution?

Comment: Ha. That'd be a red herring.

Comment: I have [one more location](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branchville_(Ridgefield)) but it's probably wrong as well. I need some sleep now.

Comment: Would it be Hiddenite, North Carolina, named after hiddenite, the variety of spodumeme which was first found there? Incidentally, the name *Hidden*ite jives with the clue "concealed in plain sight."

Comment: @DaniilAgashiyev That  works as answer to both questions.

Answer (score 8):

### Partial solution

The PNG file in the question is corrupted, with 19 extra bytes in the second `IDAT` chunk.

At offset `0x000106BC` in the file there is a 19-byte text string:

> `PCLOANICNESAILGEHDT`, which is `PLAINSIGHT` interleaved with `CONCEALED` (i.e. "concealed in plain sight").

Removing the offending bytes results in an uncorrupted image:

> [image]

It looks like a word puzzle from here on out, so I'll leave the final solution to someone else.

Comment: [The text contains the words PLAINSIGHT and CONCEALED plus the remaining L8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPFy8.png)

Comment: Maybe removing the extra bytes will fix the image.